# div left and div right not floating side by side in container

Tags: css, html

here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xploit/fZw9N/)

```
#wrapper {
    margin:1px;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    clear:both
}
#wrapperR {
    margin:1px;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    float:right;
    clear:both;
}
```

in my page it looks like this

```
  L
   R
```

but i want it to look like    LR
I would like for the  and all its content to remain left while
  remains right and side by side.

I've added clear:both; to both divs, i've even created a .clear{clear:both;} and i've adjusted the widths and paddings and margins, but I still can't float them side by side.

I'm wondering what I am over looking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `clear:both` from:

```
#wrapperR {
margin: 1px;
height: auto;
width: auto;
float: right;
clear: both; /* REMOVE THIS LINE*/
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fZw9N/6/)**

The `clear:both` rule here means that this element will be placed below any floated elements before it.

Answer (score 0):

errrr. surely clear:both is your problem? that will stop them from being side to side.

also try displaying them inline-block:

`display:inline-block`

Comment: oh actually sorry if your floating them i guess you don't really need to worrk about displaying them inline.

Answer (score 0):

Place these mod on your css:

```
#wrapper{margin:1px; height:auto; width:auto;float:left;}
#wrapperR{margin:1px; height:auto; width:auto; float:right; }
#column_l {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    float:left;
}
#column_r {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right:5px;
    float: left;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left:60%;

}
```

Removing `clear:both` from `wrapper` and `column_[l|r]`

If you want your right column more higher ("attached to the menu"), you must play with the attribute `top: -X px`

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper p {
   position : relative;
   float: left;
}
```

And adjust your text to have place for floating